# PHP breaking CSS layout

Tags: php, css

Please observe the following site I'm working on, specifically the Contact page:

http://anyonecanplayguitar.org/test/

The bounding box serving to contain the text content of the page gets stretched too far down the page and some of the margins of the main nav get screwy on this page alone. This is the only PHP document on the site, so I reckon that has something to do with it. It seems as if there's unnecessary whitespace intruding into the page, but I can't identify where it is or where it's coming from.

My searches through the various similar posts on this site did not help me understand or resolve this problem. I'm new to PHP, so I'm not entirely sure I understand yet how it can affect the HTML and CSS of a page. Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we get some source code? :)

Comment: `php` can't break CSS layout. it is YOU who is breaking it. see the markup.

Comment: Please check if the encoding of the php, css, html files are corresponding. If not, that might cause some incompatibilities.

Comment: PHP only serves dynamic HTML content. You can always modify your css to get the page layout you want.

Comment: `#content { height: 100%; }` would be the problem. It is sizing the content div to the same height as the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i remove the #content { heigth: 100%; } it works for the contact page. But on the other sides it works also with the height 100%.
But your contact page isnt sending a Doctype! The others send html as doctype. So your document is handled different on contact page (i think html4 is default and html is html5)
Add a Document type at the php site output and it will work i think.

PHP can't break any css. It !just! produce HTML as output. So it is your different output whats causing this problem.

Comment: Indeed! I certainly didn't mean to imply that the PHP was at fault. With computers it's almost always the user who's at fault. :) My omission of a doctype was the culprit. I was working from some tutorials to create that page and the tutorial made use of includes, rather than an entire page of html like mine, so adding it in fixed everything. Thanks also to everyone who mentioned the height: 100% thing. I realize it is an unnecessary property that was left in from an earlier design. This is my first experience here and it's been pleasant. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

fix your css. look what happens when the window height is changed.

[image: css needs fixing]

Answer (score 0):

I am Brazilian, then, sorry for the bad english!

You need to put your php code between escape html markup " see at the comments, please "

It's necessary because the php can count the white spaces too..!

Good Luck!

Fernando Cadastro